# Navigation property in derived types

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to entity framework and database design and I'm using database first approach, which in visual studio 2012 default to creating POCO classes with DbContext API. I'm trying to keep the POCO classes as lean as possible and I encountered a scenario where I want to generate two types from a single table. My problem is I want to move the navigation properties along with the foreign keys to the derived types. Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

NOTE: I tried to post an image of what I'm trying to do but apparently I still don't have enough reputation to do that.

Edit: Thanks to whomever gave me enough reputation to post an image. The image that I'm trying to post is below.

[image: TPH inheritance]

Thanks,

Raymond

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get a solution to this? I have a similar structure. I created a super-type table in my SQL Server DB with 2 sub-type, one has a relationship to another table. EF simply set it up for me. But you should be able to do it by right-clicking on your entity and adding a new navigation item. You can then create a new Association (also by right clicking).

Regards

Comment: We ended up just merging everything into a single table. As of now I don't have the time to play with the concept again, but once I get the chance, I'll look into what you said and update things accordingly. Thanks.